# Is $R$ symmetric and transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, relations

Let $R$ be a relation defined on the set $Z$ by $aRb$ if $a \neq b$. Is it true that $R$ is symmetric
and transitive? If not, give an example.

1. It is symmetric because $a \neq b$ and $b \neq a$.
2. It is transitive because $a\neq b$ and $b \neq c$ so therefore $a\neq c$.

Comment: 1 is correct. Think again about 2 please.

Comment: 1 is not worded appropriately for an explanation. To show that $R$ is symmetric, you must show that *if* $a\ne b$, *then* $b\ne a$, not that “$a\ne b$ and $b\ne a$.” (If you change the word “and” to “implies,” you will have a valid explanation.)

Comment: Do you seriously believe $a \ne b$ and $b \ne c$ means $a \ne c$?  Note.  $27 \ne 5876$ and $5876 \ne 27$.  Does that mean $27 \ne 27$?

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

Do $2\ne 3$ and $3\ne 2$ imply that $2\ne 2$?

Answer (score 1):

A relation is symmetric if and only if:
$$\mathbf{\forall a \forall a ((a,b)\in R \implies (b,a)\in R)}$$
  where the domain of $a$ and $b$ is understood to be $\mathbb {Z}$.
  For transitivity you have: 
$$ \mathbf{\forall a \forall b \forall c ((a,b)\in R \land (b,c)\in R \implies (a,c)\in R)}$$
  where again the domain of discourse is understood be $\mathbb{Z}$.  From this rigorous development of the definitions you can easily see that the relation posited is symmetric since $a\neq b \implies b\neq a$. However, it is not transitive since you can have $a\neq b $ and $b \neq c$ but $a = c$ and hence the implication fails.